# Mongo find doesn't use correct index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I just create a new index, added it with a help of mongoose:

```
test.index({"source": 1, "tickers.exchange": 1, "tickers.symbol": 1, "report_date": -1});
```

In the db - I can see that index was added correctly:

```
Index Value: source_1_tickers.exchange_1_tickers.symbol_1_report_date_-1
```

Now when I try to execute the query which matches exacrtly the index, it still won't use this index but rather other one:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
    source: 'testSource',
    'tickers.exchange': { $all: ['TEST_EXCHANGE'] },
    'tickers.symbol': { $all: ['TEST_SYMBOL'] },
    report_date: { $gte: ISODate('2016-07-01T00:00:00.000Z'), 
                   $lte: ISODate('2016-09-30T23:59:59.999Z') },
    change: { $gt: 0 }
})
```

and I use `explain('executionStats');` to see which index is used it produces the following:

```
tickers.symbol_1_change_1_report_date_1
```

Trying to undestand why

Comment: Why are you using `$all` in the query instead of a just `'tickers.exchange': 'TEST_EXCHANGE'`?

Comment: yeah, I changed it to 'tickers.exchange': 'TEST_EXCHANGE', still the same result

Comment: It's using the other index because it's more efficient for your query. If `tickers` is an array, you likely want `tickers: {$elemMatch: {exchange: 'TEST_EXCHANGE', symbol: 'TEST_SYMBOL'}}` instead as I assume you're looking for a single array element that matches both?

Comment: is $elemMatch adds performance?

Comment: @JohnnyHK just switched, to $elemMatch and I don't see any performance gain... hmmm

Comment: The point is to make sure you get your query working correctly before worrying about indexing it. Using `$elemMatch` here is about correcting the query, not performance.